# Postgres has a high number of rows removed by join filter

Tags: postgresql

Postgres is performing a sub-optimal join for a number of queries with simple joins. It appears to be doing a cartesian join and then removing rows using a join filter, the explain plan below shows:

```
  Insert on sierra  (cost=7.350..26.120 rows=1 width=88) (actual rows=0 loops=1)
    ->  Nested Loop  (cost=7.350..26.080 rows=1 width=426) (actual rows=14356 loops=1)
          ->  Nested Loop  (cost=6.240..19.470 rows=1 width=304) (actual rows=14356 loops=1)
                  Join Filter: (xray_two.echo_romeo = november_three.echo_romeo)
                ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=6.240..18.380 rows=1 width=184) (actual rows=14356 loops=1)
                      ->  Nested Loop  (cost=3.970..11.980 rows=1 width=187) (actual rows=14356 loops=1)
                              Join Filter: ((lima.victor = xray_two.victor) AND (lima.three = xray_two.three))
                              Rows Removed by Join Filter: 3813025380
                            ->  Index Scan using foxtrot on echo_two lima  (cost=1.720..5.590 rows=1 width=185) (actual rows=14356 loops=1)
                                    Index Cond: ((delta = 'uniform'::timestamp without time zone) AND (zulu_tango = 1))
                            ->  Index Scan using november_hotel on mike xray_two  (cost=2.250..6.330 rows=1 width=18) (actual rows=265606 loops=14356)
                                    Index Cond: ((delta = 'uniform'::timestamp without time zone) AND (zulu_tango = 1))
                      ->  Index Scan using zulu_six on india whiskey  (cost=2.270..6.360 rows=1 width=17) (actual rows=1 loops=14356)
                              Index Cond: ((lima.delta = delta) AND (delta = 'uniform'::timestamp without time zone) AND (lima.victor = victor))
                ->  Seq Scan on kilo november_three  (cost=0.000..1.040 rows=1 width=124) (actual rows=1 loops=14356)
          ->  Limit  (cost=1.110..1.130 rows=1 width=130) (actual rows=1 loops=14356)
                ->  Sort  (cost=1.110..1.130 rows=1 width=130) (actual rows=1 loops=14356)
                        Sort Key: xray_delta.six DESC
                        Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 25kB
                      ->  Seq Scan on xray_delta  (cost=0.000..1.070 rows=1 width=130) (actual rows=1 loops=1)
                              Filter: (six < ('juliet'::cstring)::timestamp without time zone)
```

You can see that there is ~4b rows removed by the join filter. Postgres was only expecting 1 row, but actual rows returned for november_hotel were 265k. It is then looping 265k rows 14k times. What is causing the planner to execute such an inefficient join/filter scheme? Some points to note:

- This exact same code has been running on multiple servers over many months, only the most recent installation is giving this problem.
- After an analyze the execution works fine, the difference being the "mike" index scan returns 1 actual row per the 14k loops in the join.
- I've changed the autovacuum parameters to be hyper-aggressive. However sometimes new data is inserted into the "mike" table (1 hour worth of data with a table that has 4 weeks history) and the offending query is executed before the autovacuum can run anew. This results in a massive slowdown to the server again.
- All joins are using indexed columns, in the indexed order.
- I have played with config parameters such as increasing default statistics target, increasing cpu costs, decreasing random page cost, setting effective cache size to ~52G (with 70G ram allocated to postgres by the os), setting shared buffers to 6G. This hasn't solved the problem, and with the postgres plan vs actual execution so different until an analyze is performed I don't think it will.
- Why is postgres not choosing a hash join/merge join which would surely be more efficient in this case?

What is causing postgres to get the plan so wrong? I could put a band-aid on the problem by manually analyzing before executing the offending queries, but I don't think this solved the underlying problem, which could then potentially crop up anywhere in my code.

**Edit:**

As requested I've simplified the query down to its most basic level, select * from both tables, joining on all the indexed fields.

Method: I inserted a new hours worth of data, then immediately ran an explain analyze. When that finished after 4000s I ran the same explain analyze once more (by this time postgres had autovacuumed the tables), that returned in half a second. The only difference being the actual rows returned in the nested loop for table_b.

The query:

```
explain analyze
select col.*, strat.*
FROM table_a col
  JOIN table_b strat
    ON (strat.cellkey = col.cellkey
   AND strat.offerkey = col.offerkey
   AND strat.strategykey = col.strategykey
   AND strat.startdate = col.startdate)
where col.startdate = '2017-05-17 1700'
AND   col.strategykey = 1;
```

The first explain:

```
Nested Loop  (cost=4.51..13.48 rows=1 width=544) (actual time=6.210..4264064.949 rows=31169 loops=1)
   Join Filter: ((col.cellkey = strat.cellkey) AND (col.offerkey = strat.offerkey))
   Rows Removed by Join Filter: 8278642245
   ->  Index Scan using table_a_1 on table_a col  (cost=2.24..6.76 rows=1 width=494) (actual time=0.034..177.203 rows=31169 loops=1)
         Index Cond: ((startdate = '2017-05-17 17:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (strategykey = 1))
   ->  Index Scan using table_b_1 on table_b strat  (cost=2.27..6.66 rows=1 width=50) (actual time=0.020..94.664 rows=265606 loops=31169)
         Index Cond: ((startdate = '2017-05-17 17:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (strategykey = 1))
 Planning time: 4.689 ms
 Execution time: 4264074.251 ms
```

The second explain:

```
Nested Loop  (cost=4.51..341069.90 rows=36588 width=545) (actual time=0.290..538.989 rows=31169 loops=1)
  ->  Index Scan using table_a_1 on table_a col  (cost=2.24..73371.98 rows=36662 width=495) (actual time=0.168..81.488 rows=31169 loops=1)
        Index Cond: ((startdate = '2017-05-17 17:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (strategykey = 1))
  ->  Index Scan using table_b_1 on table_b strat  (cost=2.27..7.26 rows=1 width=50) (actual time=0.012..0.013 rows=1 loops=31169)
        Index Cond: ((startdate = '2017-05-17 17:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (cellkey = col.cellkey) AND (strategykey = 1) AND (offerkey = col.offerkey))
Planning time: 10.053 ms
Execution time: 543.467 ms
```

How do we explain this? Tables are regularly having data inserted into them, even with ultra aggressive vacuuming we cannot guarantee they will be freshly analyzed for each query we run.

Comment: do you mean `Seq Scan on xray_delta ...` ? not sure if can help with that information. Maybe you should try run only that subquery and see if get different result. Try to work with a db backup without getting more data inserted at the time of the testing.

Comment: After reading again look more like a postgres bug to be reported on the postgres site. But you still should include the original query and the explain plan with before and after analyze so we can compare the differences. Also try to find the smallest query where you can detect the error.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try reduce the query and replicate the result, and post the info accordingly. As I mentioned it can be tricky because you have to catch it during a window when it hasn't recently analyzed the data. Using a db backup doesn't help the cause because the problem only manifests itself on a system with changing data.

Comment: `only the most recent installation is giving this problem.` + `rows=1 width=185) (actual rows=14356` + `rows=1 width=18) (actual rows=265606` -->> statistics ar missing -->> `VACUUM ANALYZE`

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza, I've added an edit with a simplified query. Hopefully that will help clear up the problem I'm facing.